# Recommendation for JAVA Script Framework

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, user-interface, dojo

We are at the starting point of a GUI focused webapplication. Business logic will be in the background. The web GUI will have multiple languages and will also contain complex charts. Chart data will be calculated via the webservice in the background, accessed via REST interface. All input fields should get validated on entering new values. The application must also run well on tablets. What is the best Java Scripts Frameworks or any combination of framework recommanded for this approach. Is Dojo the choice or better GWT? What is your experiance, other better recommendations?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com). It has very nice controls for both desktop and mobile apps. Also it has a dataviz framework which you can use to display all kinds of charts.

Answer (score 2):

Too many possible answers. Personally I like GWT. It's very flexible. But also I'm a Java developer and I don't like Javascript, and GWT saves you (mostly) from the pain and torture of writing Javascript.

Comment: Yes, GWT is a good UI framework for tose who have a java background. +1

Answer (score 1):

Anton,

Really a matter of choice and personal taste, however, if you want to adopt a mvvm approach where your client objects are syncronised automatically, I'd suggest knockoutjs. This framework is eveolving daily and takes a remarkable amount of grunt out of complex work. Take a wander over to it:

http://knockoutjs.com/

Quote from the page:

*`By encapsulating data and behavior into a view model, you get a clean, extensible foundation on which to build sophisticated UIs without getting lost in a tangle of event handlers and manual DOM updates.`*